How to sum the value of a field in a page extension taken from another table?
Excuse me,
I have received a request to add a 'grand total amount' column on the 'Posted Transfer Receipts' page.
enter image description here
This column should be filled with the total of 'cost amount actual' from the 'Item Ledger Entry' table based on the specified filter.
enter image description here
The code I created does not display the value. Does anyone know what could be the cause?
pageextension 60535 "PostTransReceipt" extends "Posted Transfer Receipts"
{
    layout
    {
        addafter("Posting Date")
        {
            field(GrandTotalAmount; GrandTotalAmount)
            {
                ApplicationArea = All;
                Caption = 'Grand Total Amount';
            }
        }
    }

    trigger OnAfterGetRecord()
    var
        ItemLedgEntry: Record "Item Ledger Entry";
    begin
        GrandTotalAmount := 0;
        ItemLedgEntry.SetFilter("Document No.", Rec."No.");
        ItemLedgEntry.SetFilter("Cost Amount (Actual)", '>0');
        if ItemLedgEntry.FindFirst() then begin
            repeat
                GrandTotalAmount += ItemLedgEntry."Cost Amount (Actual)";
            until ItemLedgEntry.Next() = 0;
        end;
    end;

    var
        GrandTotalAmount: Decimal;
}

Please help me, thank you.
I have tried to add a 'grand total amount' column on the 'Posted Transfer Receipts' page and retrieve the value from the 'cost amount actual' field in the 'Item Ledger Entry' table. I expected the column to display the total value of 'cost amount actual' according to the specified filter. However, the column does not display any value at all; the result is empty or not as expected.

The main reason you are not getting the correct result is that Cost Amount (Actual) is a so-called FlowField.
This means that you need to instruct the SQL Server to calculate the value when retrieving the records.
To do so you need to call SetAutoCalcFields before you call FindSet (you should not use FindFirst in this case):
ItemLedgEntry.SetAutoCalcFields("Cost Amount (Actual)");


While Kasper's answer is absolutely correct, I would suggest another approach to  this task, for the reasons of performance. Since the field "Item Ledger Entry"."Cost Amount (Actual)" is actually a value calculated from the Value Entry table, you can query Value Entry directly.
Instead of the loop on item ledger entries, run CalcSums on value entries:
    trigger OnAfterGetRecord()
    var
        ValueEntry: Record "Value Entry";
    begin
        ValueEntry.SetRange("Document No.", Rec."No.");
        ValueEntry.CalcSums("Cost Amount (Actual)");
        GrandTotalAmount := ValueEntry."Cost Amount (Actual)";
    end;

This will eliminate the loop on the client side, pushing the calculation to SQL Server. Besides, the SQL query itself will be much more efficient.
Loop on Item Ledger Entry with AutoCalcFields will generate a query with a JOIN and OUTER APPLY
SELECT
    "Item Ledger Entry"."timestamp" AS "timestamp","Item Ledger Entry"."Entry No_" AS "Entry No_","Item Ledger Entry"."Item No_",

    ...
    <All the other table fields here if you don't use SetLoadFields>
    ...

    ISNULL("SUB$Cost Amount (Actual)"."Cost Amount (Actual)$Value Entry$SUM$Cost Amount (Actual)",0.0) AS "Cost Amount (Actual)" FROM "CRONUS".dbo."CRONUS International Ltd_$Item Ledger Entry$437dbf0e-84ff-417a-965d-ed2bb9650972" AS "Item Ledger Entry" WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)
JOIN "CRONUS".dbo."CRONUS International Ltd_$Item Ledger Entry$437dbf0e-84ff-417a-965d-ed2bb9650972$ext" "Item Ledger Entry_ext"  WITH(READUNCOMMITTED) 
    ON ("Item Ledger Entry"."Entry No_" = "Item Ledger Entry_ext"."Entry No_")
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT  TOP (1) SUM("Cost Amount (Actual)$Value Entry"."Cost Amount (Actual)") AS "Cost Amount (Actual)$Value Entry$SUM$Cost Amount (Actual)" FROM "CRONUS".dbo."CRONUS International Ltd_$Value Entry$437dbf0e-84ff-417a-965d-ed2bb9650972" AS "Cost Amount (Actual)$Value Entry" WITH(READUNCOMMITTED) 
        WHERE ("Cost Amount (Actual)$Value Entry"."Item Ledger Entry No_"="Item Ledger Entry"."Entry No_")) AS "SUB$Cost Amount (Actual)"
WHERE ("Item Ledger Entry"."Document No_"=@0) ORDER BY "Entry No_" ASC OPTION(FAST 50)

If you invoke SetLoadFields before FindSet, this will eliminate the JOIN, but OUTER APPLY still has to be there.
With CalcSums on the Value Entry, on the other hand, the query will be just a simple and elegant SELECT SUM:
SELECT SUM("5802"."Cost Amount (Actual)") FROM "CRONUS".dbo."CRONUS International Ltd_$Value Entry$437dbf0e-84ff-417a-965d-ed2bb9650972" "5802"
WITH(READUNCOMMITTED) 
    WHERE ("Document No_"=@0)

